# Function NETWORKDAYS.INTL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make a "retroplanning" in excel. Starting from a deadline and trying to get a startday subtracting the number of working days from it but I am getting an odd result. I think this is because the subtracting result from my formula is a negative number right?

The desired result would be:

START = DEADLINE - WORKDAYS
END = START + WORKDAYS

Any hints in here?

[image]

Comment: The parameters for the functions are as follows: 1) Start-date 2) A positive/negative integer to add/substract days. You are mixing this logic. Your current start-date is `I12-J12` and you add a huge amount of days since your 2nd parameter equals a huge integer that stands for 7-4-22. Why not just use `=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(I12,-J12)`? Would that solve it?

Comment: Totally right, thanks a lot for the hint!

Comment: Great, I'll add that in an answer for you to accept and close the thread (click checkmark). Off-topic: You have a lot more open questions. Not sure if all have answers, but try to close old questions. It's simply how the site works and a courtesy to those that helped you out.

Comment: Why not use the `WORKDAY.INTL` function?  That would provide the start date directly.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment above:

---

The parameters for the functions are as follows:

- 1. Start-date
- 2. A positive/negative integer to add/substract days.

You are mixing this logic. Your current start-date is `I12-J12` and you add a huge amount of days since your 2nd parameter equals a huge integer that stands for `7-4-22`. Why not just use:

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(I12,-J12)
```

Would that solve it?